# Vb.net Catch an "Assertion Failed"?

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, assertion

So the program I'm working on has a "Process File" Button, which opens a select file dialog box, you select a text file. The software then calls a function that pipes it in to a DLL lib in C and returns results.

This all works fine, unless the file gets moved or deleted that you are trying to process. VB throws a big "Assertion Failed" message box saying str =! NULL (which I guess is true). I have the function in a "try, Catch" statement.

[Assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sw9W.png)

Why isn't it just catching it?

I know I could just verify the file exists right before processing it, but deleting the file was a test to see if the try, catch worked, which it doesn't due to the big assertion box.

==========================================================================

```
        Try
            ProcessSongResult = ProcessSongInC(old_key(0),
                              new_key(0),
                              output_mode(0),
                              lyrics_mode(0),
                              display_format(0),
                              blank_line_mode(0),
                              song_file_path(0),
                              screen_width,
                              screen_height,
                              paper_width,
                              paper_height,
                              error_msg(0),
                              transposed_song(0),
                              num_columns,
                              column_1_end,
                              column_2_end,
                              font_size,
                              total_lines,
                              tsi(0),
                              ischord(0))

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Tranposing error encountered. Choose different settings and try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Transposing Error Encountered!")
            Exit Sub

        End Try

Public Declare Function ProcessSongInC Lib "LMSdll.dll" (
    ByRef old_key As Byte,
    ByRef new_key As Byte,
    ByRef output_mode As Byte,
    ByRef lyrics_mode As Byte,
    ByRef display_format As Byte,
    ByRef blank_lines_mode As Byte,
    ByRef song_file_path As Byte,
    ByVal screen_width As Integer,
    ByVal screen_height As Integer,
    ByVal paper_width As Integer,
    ByVal paper_height As Integer,
    ByRef err_msg As Byte,
    ByRef TransposedSong As Byte,
    ByRef num_columns As Integer,
    ByRef column_1_end As Integer,
    ByRef column_2_end As Integer,
    ByRef font_size As Integer,
    ByRef total_lines As Integer,
    ByRef tsi As Integer,
    ByRef ischord As Byte
    ) As Integer
```

Comment: can you show us your "try, Catch" statement please?

Comment: "VB throws a big "Assertion Failed" message box".  It does not, it comes from C code, the assert() function displays it.  It is not an exception so Try/Catch does absolutely nothing.  Don't call the function unless you know that all of the arguments have a proper value.  Fwiw, best thing to do with that LMSdll.dll file is to delete it from your disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the documentation for the `Debug.Assert` method?  What it's doing is the whole point.  It's supposed to provide specific information about a specific condition during debugging. The whole point is that you place an assertion before you do something that would be affected by the condition the assertion tests. While debugging, you get the message from the assertion while in a Release build you would just get an exception thrown from the code that follows. What you're seeing is what you're supposed to see. If you want to avoid the assertion then run a Release build.